# Changing the colour of a boxplot when its paired

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, boxplot

I want to change the colour of the boxplots according to what they represent, this are grouped in pairs, so my question is:

**How can i change the colour of the boxplots when they are paired?**
Considering that the first boxplot of each pair should be blue and the second one red.

This is the code, sorry if it's messy:

```
def obtenerBoxplotsAnuales(self, directorioEntrada, directorioSalida):
    meses = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio", "Julio", "Agosto","Septie.","Octubre","Noviem.","Diciem."]
    ciudades = ["CO","CR"]      
    anios = ["2011", "2012", "2013"]
    boxPlotMensual = []
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(14.3, 9)
    ax = plt.axes()
    plt.hold(True)
    for anio in anios:
        boxPlotAnual = []
        i=0
        ticks = []
        for mes in range(len(meses)):
            data1 = getSomeData()
            data2 = getSomeData()
            data = [    [int(float(data1[2])), int(float(data1[0])), int(float(data1[1]))],
                        [int(float(data2[2])), int(float(data2[0])), int(float(data2[1]))] ]
            plt.boxplot(data, positions=[i,i+1], widths=0.5)
            ticks.append(i+0.5)
            i=i+2
        hB, = plt.plot([1,1],'b-')
        hR, = plt.plot([1,1],'r-')
        plt.legend((hB, hR),('Caleta', 'Comodoro'))
        hB.set_visible(False)
        hR.set_visible(False)
        ax.set_xticklabels(meses)
        ax.set_xticks(ticks)
        plt.savefig(directorioSalida+"/asdasd"+str(anio)+".ps", orientation='landscape', papertype='A4' )
```

This is what i get:
[image: Boxplots are all the same colour]

I've read that the solution is related with the fact that `plt.boxplot(...)` returns a kind of dict object that contains a list of the lines created so the way to modify the colour of each boxplot would be access to the indexes? How for this case?

Comment: And by the way, i'm getting 23 boxplots because apparently the image is being cut, does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the colour of the return dict from boxplot as follows,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nboxes = 10

# fake up some data
spread= np.random.rand(50,nboxes) * 100
center = np.ones((25,nboxes)) * 50
flier_high = np.random.rand(10,nboxes) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10,nboxes) * -100
data =np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

# plot figure
plt.figure()
bp = plt.boxplot(data)

for i, box in enumerate(bp['boxes']):
    #Colour alternate boxes blue and red
    if i%2:
        box.set_color('blue')
    else:
        box.set_color('red')

plt.show()
```

Where you loop through all boxes in `bp['boxes']` and use the method `set_color` (you can also `box.set_markerfacecolor` and other standard matplotlib artist attributes). The `bp` dict also contains `['boxes', 'fliers', 'medians', 'means', 'whiskers', 'caps']` which can also be changed as required.